# How to share printer across two VLANS on Cisco WRVS4400N?

Tags: networking, vlan

As the title says, we have two VLANs at the office, one for authorized users and one for guests. The first VLAN contains some resources that should be only for authorized users, but the printer should be shared. At the moment, all traffic between the VLANs if firewalled, except for the printer's IP. Even though inter-VLAN routing is enabled, the guests can't access it.

If you need more specific info to solve this, please ask.

Comment: Is the printer VLAN-aware, so you can trunk both VLANs to it and simply put it on both networks? When you say guests can't access it, do you mean they can't browse to it dynamically, or do you mean that even when you manually configure a client to print to its IP address, it doesn't work?

Comment: @Spiff The printer doesn't support 802.11Q so no VLAN awareness. And by no access I mean even pings won't go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by separating the VLANS into different /24 subnets, after this inter-VLAN routing works as it should. Had some additional trouble trying to firewall there subnets, but got the unwanted IPs blocked by denying **both** incoming and outgoing traffic between the subnets. For some reason just denying traffic from the guest VLAN to the authorized VLAN didn't do anything.